# What is the meaning of line and points in the schematic of a polymer

Tags: structural-engineering, materials

In the engineering material book. It shows the following figure
[image]

The following is the text to depict the picture
"The origin of rubber elasticity is more difficult to picture than that of a crystal or glass. The long molecules, intertwined like a jar of exceptionally long worms, from entanglements—points where molecules, because of their length and flexibility, become knotted together (Figure 25.6)."

But I still don't know the point and line.

Comment: https://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.85.021808

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **dots** represent **atoms** (as Dibujo de Croquis pointed out, they can be C, H, O, F, Cl, etc.), and the **lines** represent that there's a **chemical bond** between two atoms, as exemplified by this picture: [image]
Your picture can be particularly confusing because:

1. It just draws dots for the atoms for the branches of each monomer, and skips the atoms that make the chain itself, this is standard practice (but you may imagine an atom the end of each line segment, usually carbon).
2. It decides to suddenly stop drawing those atoms at the branches near the center of the picture. They do that because they want to show how it is tangling in the middle, so in order to get a cleaner picture, they just decided to spot drawing those atoms.
3. It includes some dash lines between the atoms in the branches. This is to show that, in spite of not having a strong chemical bond, there's some weak interaction between this atoms.

Answer (score 2):

The lines are long polymer chains. They contain C, H, O, sometimes F, Cl, etc.

The points are the knots that tie the chains together. They are normally carbon or hydrogen atoms shared by two chains.